# Copy permissions Win 2000 DC to 2008 R2 DC in new domain

Tags: active-directory, permissions, windows-server-2008-r2, access-control-list

ADMT 3.1 copies users with passwords and SID history from my Win2k Domain Controller (native) to a new 2008 R2 DC (R2 functional level) in a new forest/domain.

Can ADMT also copy folders and files from the DC to external DC while preserving a complex set of ACLs, including inherited permissions?  Or is there a better way?

If there's a Win2k tool to export ACLs to a file which a Win2008 tool can use to re-create them by matching user names, that might be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Robocopy?